# Pattern matching a list with head :: tail (what pattern is used)?

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

In [the Scala spec](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#irrefutable-patterns) there are 14 definitions of "named" patterns (excluding the "pattern binders"), I can't figure out which is the right category of pattern for the following:

#### Example 1

```scala
List("A", "B", "C") match {
   case head :: Nil     => ???
   case "A" :: _ :: Nil => ??? 
   case head :: tail    => ??? 
}
```

This is purely academic as I'd like to be able to refer to the named pattern in the specification. So the question is kind of about how to interpret the spec and how to be accurate when referring to these kinds of patterns against lists.

For example 1, is it "[11. Infix Operation pattern](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#infix-operation-patterns)" as `::` (aka `Cons`) is being used infix? or "[7. Constructor Pattern](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns)" as `::` is a constructor? or if we complicate it by using literals in specific positions of the list (L3), does that invoke "[4. Literal Patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#literal-patterns)"?

Perhaps a simpler case?

#### Example 2

```scala
List(1, 4, 2, 5) match {
   case Nil          => ???
   case head :: tail => ???
}
```

What would we name that in terms of patterns used?

Comment: I am pretty sure nobody ever cared about the different names of each of those match, but rather understanding their semantics.

Comment: lol, I suspect the authors of the spec cared and I'm curious...

Comment: Is there really universally recognised names about that, not even sure, and do see how it could be useful ...

Comment: @Toby ok so, making clear it was mostly a hyperbole _(mostly meant as a joke)_, the underlying point is true and with all the good intentions. From a practical point of view, those names do not really matter _(IMHO)_. Now, you mentioned an academic interest and that is fine and hopefully, someone would answer the question.

Comment: thanks, I took it with good will and agree its a slightly odd question! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the *infix operation pattern* (8.1.11) acting as a shorthand for the *constructor pattern* (8.1.7).

With the *constructor pattern* alone, example 2 would look like this:

```
List(1, 4, 2, 5) match {
  case Nil          => ???
  case ::(head, tail) => ???
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Patterns can be combined so oftentimes we cannot speak of a single kind of pattern taking place. For example

```
case "A" :: _ :: Nil =>
```

combines at least four different kinds of pattern

- constructor pattern because `::` is a case class
- literal pattern because `"A"` is a string literal
- stable identifier pattern because `Nil` is a case object
- variable pattern because `_` is a wild-card